# How can I make a JQuery UI slider and a textbox coexist on a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, jquery-ui

I'm trying to have a jQuery UI Slider on a webpage to be displayed on an Android phone. The slider does not work by default, but when JS code that converts touch events to mouse events is dropped in (http://ross.posterous.com/2008/08/19/iphone-touch-events-in-javascript/), the slider works.

Only problem being, with the new code, if there's also textboxes on the page, they no longer focus when tapped on.

How can I solve one problem without creating another?